# Accounts struct composition error: use of undeclared crate or module `__client_accounts_{}`

Tags: anchor, rust

The following code results in "error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `__client_accounts_test_common`". I've seen other programs that use struct composition in this way and compile fine. Attempted changing the Anchor version, but it hasn't worked. Since the error comes from generated code I'm unsure the best way to proceed debugging. Any help appreciated :)

- Anchor: 0.28.0
- solana-cli 1.16.10 (src:382b3f16; feat:3712769919, client:SolanaLabs)

```
// instructions/mod.rs
pub mod test;
pub mod test_common;

pub use test::*;
pub use test_common::*;
```

```
// instructions/test_common.rs
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TestCommon<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
}
```

```
// instructions/test.rs
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

use super::test_common::TestCommon;

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Test<'info> {
  test_common: TestCommon<'info>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the code generated by the `#[derive(Accounts)]` macro from your example and I think the problem is that Anchor doesn't treat the case where you're using an `Accounts` item defined in a different file. It forgets to append `crate::` when using the generated modules for that item.

To confirm this, if you add this line to your `test.rs` file, your code will compile fine:
`use crate::{__client_accounts_test_common, __cpi_client_accounts_test_common};`

The solutions I can recommend:

- define `TestCommon` in the same file as `Test`
- or import everything from `test_common` not just `TestCommon`, so you'd use: `use super::test_common::*;`